# Http status code with libcurl?

Tags: c, http, libcurl

How do I get the HTTP status code (eg 200 or 500) after calling curl_easy_perform?

Comment: good question. another one could be, how to get a status message .. :)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html

```
CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE

Pass a pointer to a long to receive the last received HTTP or FTP code. This
option was known as CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE in libcurl 7.10.7 and earlier. This 
will be zero if no server response code has been received. Note that a 
proxy's CONNECT response should be read with CURLINFO_HTTP_CONNECTCODE 
and not this.
```

```
curl_code = curl_easy_perform (session);
long http_code = 0;
curl_easy_getinfo (session, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
if (http_code == 200 && curl_code != CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK)
{
         //Succeeded
}
else
{
         //Failed
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The other answer is absolutely correct, but I would also like to add that it might not be wise to check the error code by hand, the `200` code is not the only code that signifies success.

I'd recoment using the libcurl option [CURLOPT_FAILONERROR](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FAILONERROR.html) that when activated will make libcurl consider `400` and `500` -category statuses a request failure and will not return `CURLE_OK` from perform.

Comment: As an extension to this, depending on the options set, there are other non "200 series" codes that are a success, albeit with the understanding that more work is necessary, Two of the best known being 301 and 302.  Certainly curl can be set up to handle these automatically, but there may be cases where the application might want to handle them itself.  One possibility might be when https:// is in use with client authentication, and a completely new certificate chain is needed for the target of the 301 / 302 result.

Comment: What is the problem to just check manually if status code is < 400?