# Libcurl does not give a response but verbose mode shows that the server sent one

Tags: c++, libcurl

My program makes a series of requests to a few different websites. Every request works perfectly except for one.

I send the request successfully, and the curlcode given back from `easy_perform` is 0, but when I try to print/parse the response string it is empty. Using verbose mode, it shows that the `Content-Length` of the server's response is around 4000.

I thought maybe that the response was too big but Libcurl's defaulted to 16000 (checked this on my system as well). It could possibly be that the callback function is never being called, but I don't know how to check this.

Every other request has worked fine so i am not sure why it is not working. I can't give code, but instead I'm looking for any common problems that cause this, and if anyone else has experienced this. I only see two stack posts about this, and none gave any solution.

Similar questions to mine:
[How to get the HTTP response string using Curl in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994203/how-to-get-the-http-response-string-using-curl-in-c/45017565).

Comment: link to the other questions?

Comment: posted in inital question @koo5

Comment: without code we can't do much